# Slicing an array in python, understanding the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What does this piece of code mean in python?

```
b[:,2]
```

I am not sure what the ,2 part is saying.

Thanks.

Comment: It's basic numpy indexing.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Numpy index", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid slice syntax.. should never be a , inside the [] unless you are using a slice object.

example:

```
sliceObj = slice(1, 3)
```

Comment: Python's slice syntax is extensible to allow for what OP posted. Several libraries do it. Numpy would be the most well known example.

Comment: `b[:,2]` gets executed as `b.__getitem__(tuple([slice(None,None,None), 2]))`.  That is, a tuple is passed to the indexing method of the object.  For a basic Python list, this will raise an error.  For a numpy array this will work fine.